# Storing the option values of a select box and storing them into a variable (by comma separated values)

Tags: javascript

How can I store the list of option values from a select box into a variable, delimited by comma?

ie:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
<select id="fruits">
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
  <option value="kiwi">kiwi</option>
  <option value="mango">mango</option>
  <option value="pear">pear</option>
  <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
</select> 
</body>

</html>
```

The var would be the following:

```
var x = "orange,banana,kiwi,mango,pear,strawberry"
```

Comment: Do you know what a "for loop" is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest, at its simplest:

```
var select = document.getElementById('fruits'),
    opts = select.getElementsByTagName('option'),
    x = [];

for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
    x.push(opts[i].value);
}

x = x.join();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AvkKg/1/).

Answer (score 1):

`<select>`s have a property called `options`. You can iterate it like a regular array. You can then add their values to another, simple array and use `join` to make a comma seperated list out of it.

```
// Get the select
var select = document.getElementById("fruits");

// This array will hold the values only
var values = [];

// Iterate the options
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
  // Store the value inside our array
  values.push(select.options[i].value;
}

// Make a comma seperated list
var x = values.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var x = document.getElementById('fruits').options;
var values = [];
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    values.push(x[i].value);
}
var val = values.join(",");
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Uka6W/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using `getElementsByTagName('option')` and a `for` loop are your friends here.

[JSFIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RAqbD/1/)

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var x = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    x.push(options[i].value);
}
x = x.join(', ');
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<select>
<script language="text/javascript">
var x = new Array("orange,banana,kiwi,mango,pear,strawberry");

for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
document.write("<option value=\""+states[i]+"\">"+states[i]+"</option>");
}
</script>
</select>
```

Comment: You should read the question again. He wants to produce the comma seperated string from the select, not the selected from an array.